# Angular service function reset not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following service:

```
app.service('ItemService', function() {

    my_items = [];

    var removeItem = function(newObj) {
        var toRemove = newObj;
        var indexOf = my_items.indexOf(toRemove);
        my_items.splice(indexOf, 1);
    };

    var resetItems = function(){
        my_items = [];
    };

    var getItems = function(){
        return my_items;
    };

    return {
        removeItem: removeItem,
        resetItems: resetItems,
        getItems: getItems
    }; 
});
```

and in my controller i have:

```
$scope.my_items = ItemService.getItems();

$scope.myCheckPush = function(item) {
    ItemService.addItem(item);
}

$scope.myCheckRemove = function(item) {
    ItemService.removeItem(item);
};

$scope.reset = function () {
    ItemService.resetItems();
};
```

Here my remove function works well. But the reset function is not working as expected. Any ideas what i might be doing wrong?

Comment: "not working" in the sense what is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `my_items` and `$scope.my_items` point to the same array. When you do `my_items = []`, you just remove the reference from my items, but since `$scope.my_items` still holds the reference the array is not deleted.

To delete the array use `my_items = 0`, which will actually delete the array's contents effecting `$scope.my_items` as well.

```
var resetItems = function(){
    my_items.length = 0;
};
```